# vb.net Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. 2012

Tags: math, overflow

Hi i keep getting this error

Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

with this code please help me fix  thank

```
 Dim text As String = "hotel165593"
    Dim char_ As Char() = text.ToCharArray()
    Dim num As ULong = 3074457345618258791UL
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim num2 As Integer = char_.Length
    While i < num2
        num += Convert.ToUInt64(char_(i))
        num *= 3074457345618258799UL
        i += 1
    End While

    End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like the number you're initialising `num` with is already bigger than the maximum ULong in VB (I presume this is VB/.Net?).  If that's not bad enough, your code then goes on to attempt to multiply this by (almost) an equivalent value which will definitely send it into overflow territory.

Comment: If this is Visual Basic, `ULong` goes up to `18446744073709551615`. So he's almost definitely overthrowing in the loop.

Comment: so it cannot work in VB?